# Fastify returns FST_ERR_CTP_INVALID_CONTENT_LENGTH

Tags: fastify

I'm struggling with pretty weird error I'm getting from the Fastify on Node JS.

The server has a post service which is supposed to handle requests of gzipped JSONs body.

When I try to test it using *curl* or any other http client, I'm getting **Request body size did not match Content-Length**

My request does provide the Content-Length, the length of compressed file

```
 curl -v -i http://127.0.0.1:8081/eventproxy/track -H 'Content-Encoding: gzip' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Content-Length:479" --data-binary @sampleBatch.json.gz
```

I'm pretty sure it's related to the Fastify,  but can't figure out what I'm missing. Any idea how to get it working.

Thanks

Comment: Did you use fastify-compress plugin?

Comment: no, but something tells me it's not relate, I use zlib to handle gzip requests

Comment: The error is triggered when the bytes received are != from the bytes expected in the content length. So are you sure the body is 479 bytes?

Comment: I provide the file size of sampleBatch.json.gz. Seems like it's not related to the my request, I'm waiting from the fastify guys to help me with this

Comment: I'm one of them :)

Answer (score 3):

You need to change approach because the default content parser doesn't manage compression and will try to parse the `body`.

So to manage the compression you can overwrite the default `addContentTypeParser` and add the decompression logic:

```
const zlib = require('zlib')
const port = 8081
var fastify

fastify = require('fastify')({ logger: true })

/**
 * Setup an fastify server and define port to listen all incoming requests for this application
 */
const setUpFastify = () => {
  fastify.addContentTypeParser('application/json', { parseAs: 'buffer' }, function (req, body, done) {
    if (req.headers['content-encoding'] && req.headers['content-encoding'] === 'gzip') {
      zlib.gunzip(body, function (err, dezipped) {
        if (err) {
          done(err, null)
        } else {
          done(err, JSON.parse(dezipped.toString('utf-8')))
        }
      })
    } else {
      done(null, JSON.parse(body.toString('utf-8')))
    }
  })

  fastify.post('/track', function (req, reply) {
    reply.send(req.body)
  })

  fastify.listen(port, 'localhost', () => {
    console.log('Worker listening on ' + port + ` PID: ${process.pid}`)
  })
}

setUpFastify()
```

Note that fastify uses [`secure-json-parse`](http://npmjs.com/package/secure-json-parse) to parse the json string.

And the curl, note the `--data-binary`:

```
curl --request POST \
  --url http://127.0.0.1:8081/track \
  --header 'Accept: */*' \
  --header 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate' \
  --header 'Connection: keep-alive' \
  --header 'Content-Encoding: gzip' \
  --header 'Content-Length: 739' \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --header 'Host: 127.0.0.1:8081' \
  --data-binary @package.json.gz
```

PS trying the curl with the `@`, the payload sent was 1-byte length